# rolling weighted moving average pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've scoured stackoverflow, and I can't find exactly what fits the bill for me.

I'm calculating a weighted moving average for a rolling window.

The equation is:

```
 #weighted average temp with smoothing factor, a
 #T_w = sum[k=1,24](a^(k-1)*T(t-k)) / sum[k=1,24]a^(k-1)
```

Seems easy enough, but I need to apply this average to a rolling window.  I can do rolling mean (simple moving average):

```
 T_ = pd.DataFrame()
 T_ = temps['T'].rolling(window=24).mean()
```

But now I want to apply weights for ONLY the window I'm averaging over. 
Python's .ewm() doesn't cut the mustard, because I want the weights to be just for the window I'm "rolling" over.

I've found a few snippets that seem like they might work, but components fail:

```
from functools import partial

window = 13
alpha = 1-ln(2)/3    # This is ewma's decay factor.
weights = list(reversed([(1-alpha)**n for n in range(window)]))
ewma = partial(average, weights=weight)
rolling_average = series.rolling(window).apply(ewma)
```

Here, the problem I've run into is how partial() calls average() -- this was introduced here - [Create a rolling custom EWMA on a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836482/create-a-rolling-custom-ewma-on-a-pandas-dataframe) - but I can't comment yet (newb), and I don't know where to take this.

Another solution I have implemented, but it doesn't do exactly what I need:

```
alpha = 0.1    # This is my smoothing parameter
weights = list(reversed([(1-alpha)**n for n in range(window)]))
def f(w):
    def g(x):
        return (w*x).mean()
    return g
T_ = pd.DataFrame()
T_ = temps['T'].rolling(window=24).apply(f(weights))
```

Based on a proposed solution here: [Calculating weighted moving average using pandas Rolling method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742797/calculating-weighted-moving-average-using-pandas-rolling-method)
The problem with this approach is that it calculates the mean, whereas I need effectively something like this:

```
return (w*x).sum() / w.sum()
```

But that doesn't work, because

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

How do I calculate a rolling weighted moving average with a specified window (here, the last 24 hours), and a specified smoothing parameter a (which is only applied to the last 24 hours) ?

Comment: Have you considered [`np.average()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html)'s weights attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `return (w*x).sum() / w.sum()`, try `sum(w*x) / sum(w)`. This will get you past the `AttributeError` at least.

`sum` is a Python built-in that will work on any iterable holding objects that can be summed (i.e. added objects that can be added together with `+`). Examples of these objects include `int`, `float`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the raw=True in .apply function. it makes the input as ndarray. then you can multiply that with normalize weights:
`temps.rolling(24, axis=1).apply(lambda x: np.sum(x * w), raw=True)`

Comment: Per the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) 
"the passed function will receive ndarray objects instead. If you are just applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve much better performance."